# How to add icon to a connection in jsplumb?

Tags: jsplumb

I was trying to figure out how to add an icon to connection. This is what I intend to do:

1. When a user hovers over a connection, a trash icon should appear above/below the connection
2. When the user clicks on it, it should delete that connection

Right now, to add the trash icon to the connection, I use the following code to add a connectorOverlay.

```
["Custom",{create:function(component){ 
  return $('<img class="delete-connection" style="display:block;" src="../static/img/Delete.png">');
  },location:0.5
}]
```

I'm trying to add an event to the icon to delete the connection on click through

```
$('.delete-connection').click(function(){
  //jsplumb.detach code goes here
})
```

But it is invoking the connection click event rather than the event for icon.

As per the answer suggested, I tried the following code:

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-connection',function(){
console.log('hit')
//detach connection code goes here
});
```

Please correct me if I'm making a mistake in code.

The jsfiddle link for the question: [jsfiddle.net/cipher42/p9gdc4vm](http://jsfiddle.net/cipher42/p9gdc4vm/)

Comment: have you checked the docs & demos ? Also, what have you tried ? https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/docs.html https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html

Comment: also read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, Thanks for showing interest in the question. Right now, I'm using a custom overlay for adding the icon. I've added the code that I use in the question. I'm trying to figure out how to bind a click event to the icon's class

Comment: can you create a fiddle to play with ?

Comment: Hi, really sorry for the delay. Here's the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/gqru4sax/1/

Comment: The updated jsfiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/cipher42/p9gdc4vm/

Comment: please edit the question and add the fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections are created dynamically and hence, the overlays might not be present in the DOM when you're attaching the click handler to the delete icon overlay.

Try to attach the click handler as below :

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-connection',function(e){
  //detach the connection here
});
```

There are many reasons as to why the fiddle in the question doesn't work.

1. Overlay `<img>` tag was not having `delete-connection` class. The correct attribute to give overlays an class is `cssClass`.

   ```
   ["Custom", {
       create: function (component) {
           return $('<img style="display:block;" src="https://lh6.ggpht.com/5I4BgwoxVAZH5vcPXwdjuNQ6Ellx9YCGgOYif7o2rMwJ2X7sCV96CqXy3OG4XCfwwhGm2C4=w20">');
       },
       location: 0.5,
       cssClass: 'delete-connection'
   }]
   ```
2. The fiddle was throwing error on jsPlumb.animate & hence, the click handler was never attached in the first place.

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nitincool4urchat/p9gdc4vm/9/

References:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hi, I tried using this in my code. But still was not able to perform delete. I've attached the fiddle in the comment.

Comment: The click event did not hit the above handler function(I had tested it with a console.log). I've added the click handler in the question details.

Comment: If you inspect the images, they don't contain the class `delete-connection` and hence, the click is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'm able to delete connections when a static image is overlayed on the connections though I'm not able to figure out why I am not able to delete the same connection based on a icon overlay that appears on hover.

Comment: I've figured out the hover part. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We can add events like this:

```
                ["Custom", {
                    create: function (component) {
                        return $('<img style="display:block;background-color:transparent;" src="img/delete.png">');                     
                    },
                    location: 0.5,
                    cssClass: 'delete-connection',
                    events:{
                        click:function(params) {
                            alert("hello!");
                        }
                    }
                }]
```